# How do you print a message multiple times using a void function with 2 parameters?

Tags: c++

[This is what I want my code to look like when ran. I know how to get line and display it but not where to place the amount of times it should be ran]

Type a message: Hello there!

How many times would you like your message to be displayed: 3

Hello there!

Hello there!

Hello there!

Comment: You should add the code you're working with to the question and also the output desired as text, not an external link.  The short answer is to use some sort of loop, but with no code it's impossible to know what you have going on.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for somthing like this:

```
void myFunc(string msg,int times){
  for (int x = 0; x < times; x++){
    cout << msg << endl;
  }
}
```